# Mean of the sample obtained

Tags: r

I have this information:

```
Student:  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
   Mark: 85  62  90  85  64  72  70  59  66  70
```

So I did this:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
y <- c(85, 62, 90, 85, 64, 72, 70, 59, 66, 70)
```

And I wanted to take 10 samples of 4 students and then obtain the mean of those students. I took the samples using the next command 10 times (sample1, sample2, ..., sample10):

```
sample1 <- sample(x, 4, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL)
```

Is there any easier way to obtain the samples?

How could I obtain the mean of **those samples** programming?

I have tried the following:

```
meansample1 <- mean(sample1)
```

Comment: I tried meansample1<-mean(sample1) but I get the mean of the number of the students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the mean marks for four students with:

```
mean(sample(y, 4, replace = FALSE))
```

Then, we can replicate this task 10 times with `replicate()`:

```
replicate(n = 10, mean(sample(y, 4, replace = FALSE)))
# [1] 78.75 72.25 78.00 70.25 74.25 79.25 72.25 64.25 76.50 69.00
```

Comment: Doing this I got the result I want, but I wanted to get the sample of students ( for example: 1, 2, 5, 8) and then obtain the mean of their marks (85, 62, 64 , 59)... something that could combine both vectors (I´m not sure if what I am asking is possible, I´m an absolute beginner in R) Best regards.

Comment: I assumed `x` "lines up" with `y` If that's the case, you could do `names(y) <- x` and then look at `sample(y, 4, replace = TRUE)`. It will output vector with the students as the names and the marks as the results.